# Change return type if it can't be deserialized in rest template?

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate, json-deserialization

I call `restTemplate`:

```
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, prepareHttpEntity(), MyDeserializedClass.class);
```

MyDeserializedClass:

```
public class MyDeserializedClass {

    private final String id;
    private final String title;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyDeserializedClass(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                    @JsonProperty("title") String title) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

When there is no object inside json I'm getting `MyDeserializedClass` with `null` values.

I've tried to annotate `MyDeserializedClass` with 
`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` but with no luck.

Is there any way to retrieve another object (or some kind of callback) in such situation?

Comment: Will `null` or some sort of MyDeserializedClass subclass instead of `MyDeserializedClass with null values` fix it for you?

Comment: Why you don't return strings and use jackson to map it? if it is null will be easy to detect.

Comment: @varren If I get null instead of an object with null values then it would satisfy me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use static function as your main `@JsonCreator` instead of constructor

```
public class MyDeserializedClass {

    private final String id;
    private final String title;

    public MyDeserializedClass () {}

    @JsonCreator
    public static MyDeserializedClass JsonCreator(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("title") String title){
        if (id == null || title == null) return null;
        //or some other code can go here

        MyDeserializedClass myclass = new MyDeserializedClass();

        myclass.id = id; // or use setters
        myclass.title = title;

        return myclass;
    }
}
```

This way you can return `null` or some sort of MyDeserializedClass subclass  instead of `MyDeserializedClass with null values`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to deserialize object by yourself i.e.:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, prepareHttpEntity(), String.class);
try {
   MyDeserializedClass myClass = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.body, MyDeserialized.class);
   return ResponseEntity.ok(myClass);
} catch(IOException e) {
   //log exception
   return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```